# IPhone Pawn piece glyph rendering

Tags: android, html, ios

I'm working on a chess web app game and I'm using simple HTML glyphs to represent my pieces, I've tried both setting them in HTML as well as css. In both cases everything looks great on a desktop web browser, but on an IOS mobile my black pawns are overwritten by mobile native ones, does anyone know how to prevent this from happening and force the pieces to render as 2d desktop versions on ios and droid devices? I'm hoping that i do not have to use images.

IOS  mobile browser

[image: IOS Mobile browser]

Desktop browser

[image: Desktop browser]

Comment: Using **Menlo** font seems to give consistent glyphs.

Answer (score 1):

I think you’re thinking of a [variation selector](https://mts.io/2015/04/21/unicode-symbol-render-text-emoji/). It’s a Unicode character that “forces” the character before it to render as text or an emoji. However, browser and OS support varies widely, so it would probably be safer to use images, vectors, or a custom font instead.

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing is appending \FE0E to all of my glyphs, this informs the browser to remove the extras and render the basic glyph

```
<style lang="scss" scoped>

  .black {
    &Queen{
      &:before{content:"\265B\FE0E";}
    }
    &King{
      &:before{content:"\265A\FE0E";}
    }
    &Bishop{
      &:before{content:"\265D\FE0E";}
    }
    &Knight{
      &::before{content: "\265E\FE0E";}
    }
    &Pawn{
      &::before{content: "\265F\FE0E";}
    }
    &Rook{
      &::before{content: "\265C\FE0E";}
    }

  }

  .white {
    &Queen{
      &:before{content:"\2655\FE0E";}
    }
    &King{
      &:before{content:"\2654\FE0E";}
    }
    &Bishop{
      &:before{content:"\2657\FE0E";}
    }
    &Knight{
      &::before{content: "\2658\FE0E";}
    }
    &Pawn{
      &::before{content: "\2659\FE0E";}
    }
    &Rook{
      &::before{content: "\2656\FE0E";}
    }

  }

  .chess-square{
    position: relative;
  }

  @media only screen and (max-width: 768px) { 
   .chess-square{
      position: unset !important;
    } 
  }
</style>
```